# How to use summation in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to get the summation in XSLT

I used the following code to perform it.

```
<xsl:if test="table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')]][following::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')]]">
  <xsl:variable name="summ2" select="sum(table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')]][following::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')]][12][text() != ' 0'][text() != ' '][text()[not(starts-with(.,'-'))]][text()[not(starts-with(.,'Value'))]])"/>
  <fieldSet name="NZXVolumeTraded" value="{concat($summ2,'m')}"/>
</xsl:if>
```

This works fine. But the problem is I am getting `3.2496176E7m` as the result of summation. The correct answer must be `32.496m`.

What is the mistake that I have done in my code and how can I fix that? I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Please ALWAYS provide a **reproducible** example. We cannot reproduce your problem without seeing the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is somewhere on your `text()` filters, lets try to `sum()` up numeric values only using `translate()`

```
<xsl:if test="table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')]][following::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')]]">
  <xsl:variable name="summ2" 
    select="sum(table/tr/td[preceding::td[starts-with(text()
                ,'MKTDATQ - NZX Equity Price Summary')]]
                    [following::td[starts-with(text(),'MKTDATQ - NZX Debt Price Summary')]][12]/
                        translate(text(), translate(text(), '0123456789.', ''), ''))"/>
  <fieldSet name="NZXVolumeTraded" value="{concat($summ2,'m')}"/>
</xsl:if>
```